# Disable submit button until both inputs are not empty

Tags: javascript, forms, disabled-input

I have a simple contact form, but I want to disable the submit button until both inputs are not empty anymore. I read a lot of answers about kind of the same problem, but they all get answered in jQuery, but I would like to use native JavaScript. How can I achieve this? And can it check if the button should be enabled after any kind of change to the inputs, like pasting?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $submit = $("#verzend"),
        $inputs = $('#textarea, #email');
    function checkEmpty() {
        return $inputs.filter(function() {
            return !$.trim(this.value);
        }).length === 0;
    }
    $inputs.on('keyup blur', function() {
        $submit.prop("disabled", !checkEmpty());
    }).keyup();
});
```

I found this as a good solution, but it is in JQuery

Comment: Maybe add what you have so we can help

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this with the `required` attribute. Place this on both of your `input`. The browser should block this automatically.

Comment: yeah, I already have that, but these could be easily removed in the inspector of the browser.

Comment: @MrkSmt anything can be undone by the client. you need to validate on the server too.

Comment: I do, but it for my project it is necessary to add en remove the 'disabled' attribute for my submit button.